# My Ubuntu 22.04 keeps running SMB1 protocol

Tags: networking, 22.04, samba

I purchased a Synology DS723+ NAS (under DSM 7.2-64570).
I access it without any problem from a Huawei MateBook 14s running Ubuntu 22.04.

I can't do it, however, from an Acer Swift 5 also running Ubuntu 22.04.
Seen from this PC, I get the following message:

```
Unable to access location
Failed to get list of shares from server: Invalid argument.
```

When I look at my NAS log, the connection attempt gives the following message:

```
Host [192.168.1.22] failed to connect via [SMB] due to [SMB1 not permitted].
```

While the message obtained after a successful connection with the other PC is the following:

```
User [xxx] from [xxx(192.168.1.36)] via [CIFS(SMB3)] accessed shared folder [Photos].
```

I tried to compare the differences between the 2 PCs running Ubuntu 22.04 without success.
Samba was not initially installed on the Acer Swift 5 initially, but the installation did not correct the problem.
After reading different posts, I understand that the SMB1 connection is disabled by default since Ubuntu 20.04: I therefore do not understand why the Acer Swift 5 seems to connect like that.

And when I run `journalctl -f` on my Acer and then try to connect to the NAS, here is what I get:

```
oct. 09 21:56:32 xxx gvfsd[9205]: smbXcli_negprot_smb1_done: No compatible protocol selected by server.
oct. 09 21:56:47 xxx gvfsd[9205]: smbXcli_negprot_smb1_done: No compatible protocol selected by server.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Files ( Nautilus ) go to **Connect to Server** and ask for the server AND it's share explicitly. For example:

```
smb://192.168.1.22/Photos
```

The problem is a design flaw in gvfsd-smb-browse. Even though SMBv1 is disabled in samba itself it still allows a force setting to that dialect which gvfs uses to "discover" ( browse ) available hosts on the network.

The gvfs developers think that is the only way to discover hosts on the network. This isn't true but it is what it is.

Comment: Thanks Morbius1: this workaround does work.